# A popover in an iPhone when clicking on a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem, popover

I would like to show a popover when the user clicks on a `UIBarButtonItem`. To make a popover work on an iPhone, I have searched and found [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover)

**Edited** : Sorry, my question was confusing. I was trying to draw something similar to the iPad popover, but in an iPhone. I was asking if there is an alternative to it, such as adding a UIView over the other views or a new component from the iPhone SDK.

Thanks.

Comment: So what would you like to say? What is your question?

Comment: wats you question here??

Comment: sorry, my question was confusing. I was trying to draw something similar to the iPad popover, but in an iPhone. I was asking if there is an alternative to it, such as adding a UIView over the other views or a new component from the iPhone SDK.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [FPPopover](https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover)

The code is really simple and has a lot of automatic things

```
//the view controller you want to present as popover
YourViewController *controller = [[YourViewController alloc] init]; 

//our popover
FPPopoverController *popover = [[FPPopoverController alloc] initWithViewController:controller]; 

//the popover will be presented from the okButton view 
[popover presentPopoverFromView:okButton];
```

Answer (score 1):

add a target to your UIBarButtonItem

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"button!" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action: @selector(showPopover:)];
```

and in your target do something like this:

```
- (void)showPopover:(id)sender
{

    popoverController = [[[WEPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController] autorelease];
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame 
                                            inView:self.view 
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown
                                          animated:YES];
}
```

this code was adapted from the sample provided with WEPopover https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover/blob/master/Classes/WEPopoverViewController.m